# Meaning of `t a -> b` in type of foldl

Tags: function, haskell, types, signature, fold

I have checked signature of `foldl` function and this is the result:

```
> :t foldl
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

I am confused about this part `t a ->b` what does this part mean?
Is my guess correct that it means that 3rd argument of `foldl` function is a `Foldable` data structure which contains elements of type `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. `t` is a member of the `Foldable` typeclass, and we it is thus a foldable over elements of `a`.

If for example `t` is a `t ~ []`, then the signature is:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [] a -> b
```

or less canonical:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

But `t` can be another `Foldable` like a `Maybe`, `Tree`, `Either c`, etc. We thus can use `Foldl` on such structures:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Maybe a -> b
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Either c a -> b
```